# Minimum of exponential distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, exponential-distribution

Let's say we have three independent random variables $X, Y$ and $Z$ with Exponential distributions of parameter 1.

What is the probability 
 $$ P( X = \min(X,Y,Z)) \quad ?$$

I obtained that it is $1/3.$ Anyone could confirm me that it is correct?

Comment: The outcome is correct and follows immediately from symmetry.

Comment: Can you type out your steps to show how you've obtained this?

Comment: Oh, really, so the answer is independent of the underlying distributions... I did the direct calculation $$P(X < Y, X < Z ) = \int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty \int_x^\infty e^{-x}e^{-y}e^{-z} \: dz \: dy \: dx = 1/3$$

Comment: More generally if $(T_i)$  are independent Exponential RVs with rates $\lambda_i$ then $T=\min \{T_1,\dotsc,T_n\}$ is exponential with rate $\lambda=\lambda_1+\dotsc+\lambda_n$ and $\mathbb{P}(T=T_i)=\lambda_i/\lambda$ and one can check this reduces to your case with all $\lambda_i=1$ and $n=3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F_{min}(x) = P(W_{min} \leq x)$$ $$= 1- P(W_{min} > x)$$$$= 1-P(X > x; Y > x; Z> x)$$
$$= 1 - [1 - F_X(x)][1 - F_Y(x)][1 - F_Z(x)]$$

$$ = 1-(1-1+e^{-x})^3 = 1-e^{-3x}$$

$$f_{min}(x) = 3e^{-3x}$$

$$E(X_{min}) = \frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Average $P(Y,\,Z>x)=\exp -2X$, viz. $\int_0^\infty \exp -3xdx=\frac{1}{3}$.